# Конвертация String в Int

Tags: c#

Почему такой код

```
string a = "45";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(a));
```

выводит "45"
а такой

```
string a = "45";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(a[0]));
```

выводит "52" а не "4"? Как получить "4"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> выводит "45"

Читаем MSDN:

> Преобразует заданное строковое представление числа в эквивалентное 32-разрядное знаковое целое число.

...

> выводит "52" а не "4"?

Снова читаем MSDN:

> Преобразует значение заданного символа Юникода в эквивалентное 32-битовое целое число со знаком.

Здесь под значением подразумевается номер в таблице символов.

...

> Как получить "4"?

Например, вот так:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(0,1)));
```

**upd.** Уже обсуждалось [на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665978/c-sharp-why-does-this-return-49-convert-toint321).

Comment: Flammable: то есть

    Convert.ToInt32('a') == 52
    Convert.ToInt32("a") == 4

? Забавно, не знал.

Comment: @VladD не верьте ему, он шутит. Или это Вы шутите? Вторая строка даст ошибку.

Comment: @alexlz: ой, опечатка, сорри. Имелось в виду

    Convert.ToInt32('4') == 52
    Convert.ToInt32("4") == 4

(<http://ideone.com/x2brzL>)